# Did any Navi get angry at HaShem?

Tags: tanach, navi-prophets

At any point in the Torah does Avraham Avinu, Moshe Rabbeinu, or any of the other great Neviem ever get angry with HaSem?

Comment: Numbers 11:11-15?

Comment: @DoubleAA Is he angry there, or just exasperated? Ditto for Shemos 5:22-23.

Comment: How about Shmuel 1:15:11

Comment: Moshe must have been extremely empathetic to say he would rather die than see the Jewish ppl suffer over their dinner option

Comment: @Lages According to the Gemara, they were speaking euphemistically when they said they wanted to “eat.”

Comment: @DoubleAA Both of those explicitly say they were angry - why don’t you post them as an answer?

Comment: @DonielF I’m not following, eating is a euphemism for what exactly?

Comment: @Lages Arayos. The Gemara is [Yoma 75a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.75a.6); note in the continuation of the Gemara that even the opinion which takes these Pesukim literally also takes them euphemistically.

Comment: Are you specific about prophets and specifically in the Torah? If not, we do find a case where King David was angry with G-d.

Answer (score 0):

Yonah was angry at G-d for forgiving the people of Ninveh. See Yonah 4:1-2. In verse 4 , the term חרה implying "anger" is used.

He was also angry that G-d killed the *kikayon*, and verse 9 also uses the word חרה .